# How to change the colour of the previous view controller from the current view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having a problem with changing the colour of a view controller. I want to tap a button on the current controller and it will change the background colour of the previous controller and save it

```
@IBAction func viewColourChange(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:
            {self.viewColourChange.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.9856258568, blue: 0.2624827082, alpha: 1)
        }, completion: nil)
        Haptic.impact(.medium).generate()
    }
```

I have it so when I click the button a specific UIView changes colour which is what I want but I also want it to change the colour of the previous controller background colour and save it

I think it has something to do with singleton or notifications but I am just getting so confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is with `NotificationCenter`. First, post a notification in your current view controller when you tap the button:

```
@IBAction func viewColourChange(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let newColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.9856258568, blue: 0.2624827082, alpha: 1)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { self.viewColourChange.backgroundColor = newColor }, completion: nil)
    Haptic.impact(.medium).generate()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .viewColorChanged, object: nil, userInfo: ["newColor" : newColor])
}
```

And add this extension somewhere in your code:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let viewColorChanged = Notification.Name("viewColorChanged")
}
```

Then add an observer for that notification in your previous view controller, for example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .viewColorChanged, object: nil, queue: .main, using: { [weak self] notification in
            if let newColor = notification.userInfo?["newColor"] as? UIColor {
                self?.view.backgroundColor = newColor // or whichever view you want to update
            }
        }
    )
}
```

---

Edit: To save the new color, you can use `UserDefaults`:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    private struct SharedKeys {
        static let viewColor = "viewColor"
    }

    static var viewColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let components = standard.array(forKey: SharedKeys.viewColor) as? [Double], components.count == 4 {
                return UIColor(
                    red: CGFloat(components[0]),
                    green: CGFloat(components[1]),
                    blue: CGFloat(components[2]),
                    alpha: CGFloat(components[3])
                )
            }
            return nil
        }

        set {
            guard let components = newValue?.cgColor.components, components.count == 4 else {
                standard.setNilValueForKey(SharedKeys.viewColor)
                return
            }
            standard.set(components.map { Double($0) }, forKey: SharedKeys.viewColor)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UserDefaults.viewColor = newColor // to save a color
UserDefaults.viewColor // to read a saved color
```

Comment: @DavidAlso Just wanted to ask how would I be able to save this colour change? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem, @StefanFletcher. If you mean how to save the new color that is applied, you could just save the color components with UserDefaults. I'll put the code in my answer above because it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 5):

When you present/push the second vc , set a delegate like

```
let second = ///
second.delegate = self
present/push/segue
```

Then inside the second vc add the var

```
weak var delegate:FirstVC?
```

Then change it

```
delegate?.view.backgroundColor = ///
```